# How to configure Cygwin git for two-factor authentication at github.com?

Tags: git, authentication, github, cygwin

I'm a git newbie. I setup an account at github.com with two-factor authentication.

I can use it fine with the MINGW32 bash shell, but I'm trying to use it with Cygwin.

This is what I get:

```
dave@ENOUGH /cygdrive/u/testG
$ git clone  https://github.com/nerdfever/<project>
Cloning into '<project>'...
Username for 'https://github.com':
Password for 'https://Nerdfever@github.com':
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/nerdfever/<project>/'
```

I did setup the user.name and user.email configs in Cygwin git.

What do I need to do to make this work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't know why somebody downvoted me, but anyway I figured it out:

```
Git under Cygwin:
a) Install git from Cygwin setup.exe
b) git config --global user.name "<username>"
c) git config --global user.password "<password>"
d) git config --global credential.helper store
e) Get personal access token per https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use/
f) git clone <project>; first time it'll ask for credentials, after that it will store them
```

Note that when git asks for your password, give it your Personal Access Token (not your password).

Comment: I also do not understand the downvote. Thanks, solved my problem. You should accept your own answer. Note: I skipped steps b) and c).

Comment: @Kai: I'm glad it helped you, but I'm still stuck. Turns out Cygwin's git doesn't work across Windows network shares.

Comment: Did you try "git clone /cygdrive/[drive letter]/folder/repo.git" or with the UNC path "git clone //computername.company.net/folder/repo.git"? Both work for me on connected network drives. Also folders, on another users machine work here like "git clone //computername/repo.git".

Comment: I see - now I can reproduce your problem. Seems like a problem with the permissions. I found some info here https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-filemodes.html But I do not know enough about that topic. I tried to edit the cygwin/etc/fstab and added noacl - but that did not do the job.

Comment: I also had to remove this part in my .gitconfig: [core] askpass = true

Answer (score 0):

I had similar situation when I changed password to GitHub.
Answer provided above works well, but option:

```
git config --global credential.helper store
```

result in situation that git stores login and password data
in you home directory as plain text in file

```
~/.git-credentials
```

Here is description how to use Git Credential Manager for Windows with Cygwin git
[How to make Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows works with Cygwin?](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/issues/146)
Hope this helps.
When you configure this you can update your password in Control Panel > Credential Manager as shown on picture below:
[image]